# Want to understand how a script thats using Cake (.ctp) works?

Tags: cakephp

not sure if this is the place to ask this question, or if this is a Cake question, its a very confussing one anyway! Knowing admin here at SO I am sure they will move/close it if necessary. And SO really is the best place to ask these questions!

Anyway, I am trying to pull a part an auction script written mainly in .php that is using Cake, and there are many .ctp files. I am trying to pull it to pieces in order to understand how it is working.

However, I have come across some functionality that I cannot get my head around how it is doing it. There are certain elements such as non application images and pages that redirect to affiliate website that have obviously been hacked by whoever before making this available for download.

Using firebug I can see file paths where it says it is getting these files from, but trying to locate them in the project folder itself or in Visual Studio solution explorer is impossible, they simply do not exist. I have made sure (in windows) I have set folder options to show hidden folders and files, but still nothing!

I have installed this project locally using WAMP server, and have also uploaded it to my live hosting account. When using the application locally, files, images and redircts do not show/redirect, but when using on the live server all these images and page redirects to affiliate accounts work.

I am guessing it must be getting this functionality from the internet, by calling a url of something... but firebug does not show any url information, only to a folder it says is local in wamp/www/app/webroot/>>>>

Is this something to do with how Cake works? I have not read up on cake yet but will do later for some bed time reading. If someone knows how this magic is happening I would really appreciate you shedding some light on the subject.

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: Show some examples of the paths you can't find in the project. May I ask if this auction script is originally made by a particular Indian company? If yes feel free to contact me, we've recycled that garbage script already more than one time for different clients... If it's the script I have in mind it's no fun to work with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Install cakePHP debugger toolbar (Debug toolkit) from here: https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit

After setting it, In the toolbar you will find (for every page) a list of the rendered files.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea! better to use Cakephp than VS.

I have installed cakephp and the debugger toolbar.. but how do you upload an existing project to cake?

Do I just add all files from Model, View, Controller folders into the corresponding folders in wamp/www/cakephp/.... ?

Im looking online but all I can find is CakeBlog or bake your very first cake... What if you've already got a cake thats baked (my auction app)... wheres the oven? lol

Thanks for the support, always appreciated..!

Answer (score 0):

any User would access a CakePHP application in a fairly standardized way.

URL -> webserver -> no file matches the URL -> `app/webroot/index.php?url=$URL`

Once you get to that point, you are in CakePHP...  And your changes are "visible" anywhere they are used.

So if you install a plugin which should have an effect on every page (like DebugKit) it would be available on every page.

The instructions on the plugin should be sufficient, but just in case:

1. Put the folder in place: `app/Plugin/DebugKit`
2. Put the config in place: `app/Config/bootstrap.php` -> `CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');`
3. Include the toolbar component in your `app/Controller/AppController.php`:

   class AppController extends Controller {
            public $components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');
   }
4. Set `Configure::write('debug', 1);` in `app/Config/core.php`.

It sounds like you were unsure WHERE to add it... maybe #3 is what you're missing...?